# Regarding collision in Map

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I was going through HashMap and read the following analysis ..

> 1. An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance: initial capacity and load factor.
> 2. The capacity is the number of buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created.
> 3. The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased.
> 4. When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice the number of buckets.
> 5. The default initial capacity is 16, the default load factor is 0.75. You can supply other values in the map's constructor.

Now suppose I have a map..

```
HashMap map=new HashMap();//HashMap key random order.
         System.out.println("Amit".hashCode());
         map.put("Amit","Java");
         map.put("mAit","J2EE");
         map.put("Saral","J2rrrEE");
```

I want collision to occur please advise how the collision would occur..!!

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand this, "please advise how the collision would occur" - why you need collision to be necessarily occured ?

Comment: "I want collision to occur". Why? That's exactly what you should be trying to *avoid*.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the exact hashmap behavior is implementation dependent. Just look at however your class library is doing the hashing and construct a collision. It's pretty simple.

If you want collisions on arbitrary objects instead of strings, it's a lot easier. Just create a class with a custom `hashCode()` that always `returns 0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want really collision to be occured then it's better to write your own custom hash code. Say for example, if you want collision for `Amit` and `mAit`, you can do one thing, just use addition of ascii values of the chars as the hash code. You will get collision for different keys.

Comment: so I will write my own overriding hashcode() method and will return same hashcode() for all..!!

Answer (score 0):

Collision will happend when 2 keys has the same hash key . 
I didn't calc your keys hash keys , but i don't think they have the same hash key, so collision will not occurred if they don't have the same hash key. 
If you will put the Same string as key than you will haves collision

Answer (score 0):

Collision here is definitely possible and not tied to hash table implementation.
[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) works internally by using [Object.hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) to map objects to buckets, and then uses a collision resolution mechanism (the OpenJDK implementation uses separate-chaining) with [Object.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

To answer your question, [String.hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) is well-defined for compatibility...

> Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a `String` object is computed as
>    `s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]`
>
> using `int` arithmetic, where `s[i]` is the *i*-th character of the string, `n` is the length of the string, and `^` indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

Or, in code (from [OpenJDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#1494))

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && count > 0) {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;
        int len = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

As with any hash function, collisions are possible. According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29#The_java.lang.String_hash_function), it states that, for example, `"FB"` and `"Ea"` result in the same value.

If you want more, it should be a trivial bruteforce problem to find collisions which have the same hash value here.

---

As a side note, I'd thought I'd point out how this is very similar to the function as in the second edition of the *The C Programming Language*:

```
#define HASHSIZE 100

unsigned hash(char *s)
{
    unsigned hashval;

     for(hashval = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
         hashval = *s + 31 * hashval;

     return hashval % HASHSIZE;
}
```